# Best practice for accessing multiple object variables

Tags: javascript

I've looked around for a question like this, but I couldn't seem to find one.

I am something of a novice to JS, and I have yet to "perfect" my coding practices.

That having been said, I've been having trouble deciding on just how necessary it is to make a reference(?) variable when accessing multiple (if even just a few) of an object's properties.

A very common example of what I mean is when I want to resize an element (both it's width and height).  On the one hand, I assume it would be slightly more performance friendly/maybe cleaner to do something like this:

```
var style=this.style;
style.width=newWidth;
style.height=newHeight;
```

However, in longer samples of code, this gets fairly tedious, and so I'm tempted to do this:

```
this.style.width=newWidth;
this.style.height=newHeight;
```

Obviously, if you're not iterating over it a bunch of times, it's not going to make very much of a difference, anyway.  But if you *were* doing so, in a case where you only want to get a few variables, **is it a big deal either way?**

Another example: Suppose I had this script:

```
for(var i=0;i<1000;i++){
  //lots of code
  element[i].font=obj.style.font;
}
```

Doing this would yield the same result:

```
var font=obj.style.font;
for(var i=0;i<1000;i++){
  var e=element[i];
  //lots of code
  e.font=font;
}
```

Will changing it to this cause a notable performance gain, or is it not even worth the bother?

For that matter, am I overlooking a normal, cleaner alternative?

Comment: this *feels like* it would be a better fit for [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/), since this is a bit too opinionated for discussion here.

Comment: Thanks, I'm new here...is there a way I can move it?

Comment: I'm not sure about moving the question, but you might want to search a bit on that side first anyway, and see if the subject has come up there.

Comment: Code Review require complete working code. At the moment the question has a lot of `//lots of code` which would make this question off-topic on Code Review. See our on-topic section for more info : http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: @Marc-Andre that's probably true as well;  I don't spend a lot of time on Code Review, but I was just trying to help find a good home for a reasonable question.  It isn't really a fit here either, since it's really focused on theory rather than bugs/issues.

Comment: I've looked around, but I couldn't seem to find anything related.  Perhaps I lack the proper terminology, in which case maybe someone could redirect me something applicable?  But assuming it has not been asked, where should I post questions like this in the future?

Comment: why don't you measure your own alternatives with console.time ?

Comment: @Touffy Good point...just did that, from what I could tell, it didn't seem to make much of a difference.  However, it would be nice to hear a professional opinion on the matter, as I am trying to train myself to be as consistent and effective as possible...

Comment: as you can see on [jsperf](https://jsperf.com/object-property-access-vs-local-variable-creating-and-a/5) and your own testing, it's about twice as fast to use a local variable. There is no ultimate answer, but 2x is generally not treated as significant (hardware and compiler improvements compensates for that faster than you can write faster code manually).